# Consultar dos veces la misma tabla

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo la tabla de vacaciones la cual tiene dos campos uno que es autoriza_id y solicita_id, hace referencias a la misma tabla de empleado, ya puedo puedo mostrar
el nombre de quien autoriza mediante el id, pero no sé como mostrar el nombre de quien solicita.
 aquí mi código:

```
 protected $rules = array(
    'nombre' => 'required|max:50'
);

public function index()
{
    $grupos = DB::table('vacaciones')
    ->LeftJoin('empleados', 'empleados.id','=', 'vacaciones.autoriza_id')
    ->select('vacaciones.*', 'empleados.nombre')
    ->get();

return response()->json(
    $grupos->toArray()
);
```

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con Laravel, pero lo que deberias de hacer es otro Join a la tabla empleados pero ahora con id de quien lo solicita y ocupar alias.

Answer (score 2):

Para lo que quieres hacer, mi solución sería que tuvieras bien creados tus modelos usando el comando `php artisan make:model NombreModelo`, una vez creados como muestro a continuación:

Modelo `Vacaciones`:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Vacaciones extends Model
{
   //Atributos



  //Relaciones
  public function solicitante(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Empleado', 'solicita_id');
  }

  public function autoriza(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Empleado', 'autoriza_id');
  }

}
```

Modelo Empleado:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Empleado extends Model
{
   //Atributos



  //Relaciones
  public function vacacionesSolicitante(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Empleado', 'solicita_id');
  }

  public function vacacionesAutoriza(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Empleado', 'autoriza_id');
  }

}
```

Si en tu controlador quieres obtener quien autoriza y quien solicita vacaciones de un registro de la tabla vacaciones bastaría con:

```
//Importar Modelo hasta arriba
use App\Models\Vacaciones;

//Método dentro de tu controlador

public function obtenerDatos(){
   $id = 1;
   $vacaciones = Vacaciones::where('id', $id)->with('solicitante', 'autoriza')->first();

   //Aquí ya tienes los datos que necesitas

   $nombre_solicitante = $vacaciones->solicitante->nombre;
   $nombre_autoriza = $vacaciones->autoriza->nombre;
}
```

Y listo, ahí tienes tus datos, no trates de evitar el uso de Eloquent ORM de Laravel, en verdad te ayuda demasiado, sólo deberías de usar expresiones "raw" cuando en verdad te sea necesario y no quede de otra.